# Lex: Why are all my tokens are undefined

Tags: c++, yacc, lex

All my tokens are coming up as undefined when g++ compiles lex.yy.c

Is this maybe related to using C++ instead of c?

All the tokens are defined with %token declarations in the yacc parser source: gh.y

Here's the relevant part of the yacc code:

```
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"
%start game

%union {
    char* str;
    int num;
    GMPARTptr gmpart;
}

%token DOTMAP DOTM DOTR DOTC DOTD DOTT DOTO DOTU DOTV COMMA;
%token PLUS MINUS SLASH SEMI RBRACKET LBRACKET;
%token PCTDOL PCTSLASH PCTT PCTAT;

%token <int> INT;
%token <str> WORD FILEPART STRING QUOTE;
%type <str> image fname label animation roomname description
%type <str> normfname
%type <int> xcoord ycoord
%type <str>roomid ID charname
```

And the first part of my lex input:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mkscript.h"
#include "gh.tab.h"
%}

DIGIT   [0-9]
STARTCHAR       [_a-zA-Z]
WORDCHAR        {DIGIT}|{STARTCHAR}
FILECHAR        {WORDCHAR}|[-.+@#$%()]
FILECHAR1       {FILECHAR}|[/" ]
FILECHAR2       {FILECHAR}|[/' ]
 /* special "start states" for matching */
%s DESC

%%
\.map   return DOTMAP;
\.m     return DOTM;
\.r     return DOTR;
\.c     return DOTC;
\.d     return DOTD;
\.t     return DOTT;
\.o     return DOTO;
\.u     return DOTU;
\.v     return DOTV;
```

But when I compile the output of lexx, I get "not declared in this scope" for all the token names.

Here are the first few lines of my error log file:

```
 g++ -DYYERROR_VERBOSE   -c -o lex.yy.o lex.yy.c
    ghlex.l: In function ‘int yylex()’:
    ghlex.l:18:8: error: ‘DOTMAP’ was not declared in this scope
      \.map return DOTMAP;
                   ^
    ghlex.l:19:8: error: ‘DOTM’ was not declared in this scope
        \.m return DOTM;
                   ^
```

=======================================================================

The full lex and yacc input files, makefile, and the error log from the make can be found at:
http://conchord.org/code/
in the files ghlex.l, gh.y, makefile, and log, respectively.

Comment: First of all, that link is 404. Even if it was valid: Do not post a link to external sites, but a [mcve] including the actual and the desired behavior in the question itself.

Comment: Ahh, didn't notice this immediately, but the link was simply malformed. It should have read: http://conchord.org/code/ That said, OP, please post your relevant C/C++ code.

Comment: Added enough of my code (and error log) to make clear what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is the line `%skeleton "lalr1.cc"`, which causes bison to generate a non-standard parser that is not compatible with normal lex.  Instead, the parser is enacpsulated in a `parser` class.

With flex, you can build a parser that is compatible with this mode, but you need an appropiate `YY_DECL` macro declaration giving `yylex` extra arguments, and you use a `yy::parser::token::` prefix on all the token names.

The easiest fix is probably just to get rid of it.

Comment: Well, I did want to write the actual processing code in an object-oriented language -- C++ or Java (or PHP).

I guess I should take out the %skeleton and use extern "C" on the functions that will be called from the parser.  Then I can write the rest of the code in plain vanilla C.

I have found several pages that claim you can write your parser in C++ or even Java, but it looks like trying to do that breaks the tokenizer.

Oh well.  Thanks.

Comment: No need to use extern "C" or do stuff in plain vanilla C -- you can use C++ just fine.  Of course, if you want to use Java or PHP you'll need to hand-write the lexer or use a lexer generator that supports Java or PHP as flex does not.

Comment: Wait, you said not to use `%skeleton "lalr1.cc"`, which is (AFAIK) how you tell Yacc/Bison to generate code for C++.  Otherwise it generates plain C code.

Comment: (addendum to previous)
But when I do that, there's still the problem of telling Lex to generate compatible code.  I'm not sure why the yacc language has a directive that makes the generated code incompatible with the lexer that is most often used with yacc.

I think the tutorials I've been using are incomplete somewhere. I just found the O'Reilly books on lex & yacc (and also flex & bison) online as PDFs.  These are more likely to be complete.

Comment: No, `%skeleton "lalr1.cc"` has nothing to do with C vs C++ code -- the code generated by bison and most versions of yacc can be compiled as C or C++ code by default.  `%skeleton "lalr1.cc"` says to use that skeleton file instead of the normal skeleton file to create a parser with a different interface.

Comment: I tried just letting flex and bison do their thing and forcing all compilations to be in C++ (CC=g++ in the Makefile).  That got me into all sorts of things that didn't work right.  It would have taken less time to write my own yylex than to solve all those.

I managed to get the compile-time errors out, but then there were a whole mess of unresolved symbols, caused by the fact that lexx/yacc (flex/bison) make different assumptions about the types of function arguments (and return types) than the compiler does if you don't get const in exactly the right places.
(to be continued)

Comment: Btw, taking out the %skeleton directive means that you can't use C++-specific features in your actions, .e.g, {theRoom->addCharacter($2, $4); }

I was originally hoping to build a "real" parse tree in the yacc code, with objects linking to each other. Instead I'm using global variables to hold the list of rooms, list of characters, etc.

Not as neat, but it will work. That's what counts.

Comment: @bgold: Using g++ to compile the parser is all you need to do -- unless you're doing something weird, it works just fine and you can use C++ code in the actions just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped all the functions I wrote that are called from the parser (e.g., addRoom) in extern "C".  Then a couple of tweaks and it compiled and linked.